# Delphi, clone an 3DObject containing childrens

Tags: delphi

I have a 3D object (TDummy) on a Viewport, as a Parent of few childrens (TCube).

This childrens has assigned some events in order to achieve collide with each other (and work correctly).

My problem:
If i clone Parent, the childrens of resulted clone didn't collide (ofcourse, first i reattach all events to childrens, but nothing happened)

Any help is highly apreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Please read [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and especially [mre]. What is moving the objects, and how? How do you detect collision?

Comment: Objects is moved with mousemove and collision is detected by checking distance between object centers

Comment: The childrens can be moved (after cloning his parent) but no receive collision, no detect targets...
While in original parent childrens collides correct

Comment: A [mre] is required.

Comment: I'm guessing that your Collision methods are poorly written. Most likely you are not properly checking which object has generated the event. I strongly suggest you edit your question by providing a code example of one of those events that handle your object collision.